# How to update Google+ status directly, without using ShareActivity?

Tags: android, google-plus

Here is how I'm sharing using Google+ app's ShareActivity. I wanted to know if I can just avoid this one extra step and directly post from my app's UI? Thanks.

```
Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this).setType("image/jpeg")
                    .setText(status.getText().toString())
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/"))
                    .setStream(Uri.fromFile(image))
                    .getIntent()
                    .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");

            startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a API available for post directly to Google+ - the ShareActivity is the preferred option as it gives the user the ability to choose which circles they want to share with.

You can write user actions directly to Google+ using App Activities: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/app-activities - these don't show up in the users stream directly however.